# How to convert dsr to rpt?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb6, rpt

I am developing web application in ASP.NET MVC 5 using C# that is the second version of an existing application that was developed in VB6, in that application there are some DSR reports. Now I want to use DSR reports in my new application but I don't know how to convert DSR report to RPT report. Kindly guide me if anyone know the way of conversion.

Comment: If you´ve access to Visual Studio 2003, you can try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa288427?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396